# Programing a new #1 remote fob for 2008 C6 Corvette

Tags: chevrolet, fob, corvette

I bought a 2008 C6 Corvette.  It came with only fob #2.  I bought a new fob #1.  When I programmed the new #1 fob, the DIC indicated it as #3.  I can't get the memory functions (recall seat, mirrors, radio stations, etc) in the car to work with the new fob.  How do I get the new fob to be recognized as #1 or get the memory functions to recognize fob #3?

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

There are actually two different procedures, one for programming new fobs and keeping the old, and a second procedure for programming all fobs. If you did the first procedure, you're just stacking fobs onto what you have. You need to do the second procedure, ensuring you program the fobs in the order you want them to coincide with memory function numbers. Here's the procedure:

> 1. Drivers window down, car off
> 2. Trunk open
> 3. Glove box open
> 4. Make sure NO Fobs are anywhere near the car. IMPORTANT.
> 5. Put key in trunk keyhole and turn key five times in less than 5 seconds.
> 6. DIC will now beep and light up and say “Off/Acc to learn” If you decide at this point NOT to do the programming now, push the TOP half of the Start button and the car will return to normal. With step 7, all previous fobs will be erased. To continue with programming:
> 7. Push bottom half of the Start button. DIC will say to wait 10 minutes and will start counting down the minutes. You may close the trunk and car door while waiting for the ten minute countdowns.
> 8. After the first 10 minute countdown, DIC will again say “Off/Acc to learn”. Push bottom half of Start button again. DIC will again start counting down the ten minutes.
> 9. After the second 10 minute countdown, DIC will again say “Off/Acc to learn”. Push bottom half of Start button again. DIC will again start counting down the ten minutes.
> 10. After this third ten minute period is over, DIC will say “Ready for Fob #1” Regardless of the number on the Fob, the FIRST Fob that is put in the glovebox slot will be recognized as Fob #1. Put the first Fob in the glovebox slot with the buttons facing to the right (passenger) side and the keyring end facing outwards.
> 11. After 3 or four seconds the DIC will beep and say “Ready for Fob #2”. Put the second Fob in the slot. The car will take a maximum of four fobs. When you have no more Fobs to program, push the bottom half of the Start button to end the programming session.
> 12. Test all buttons on the fobs to make sure they work, then take all fobs away from the car and, one by one, try using each to start the car.

Procedure pulled from [this site](https://www.corvetteforum.com/forums/c6-corvette-general-discussion/2452911-c6-comprehensive-fob-programming-instructions.html). The steps for the first procedure can be found here as well.

**NOTE:** There is [this pdf](https://www.ls2.com/boggs/c6/C6FobProgramming.pdf) which goes over the procedures as well. There are also some caveats at the top of the pdf which explains these procedures may not work in every country. (The steps and numbering listed here are for the pdf, not for the above.) Here is what it says:

> - **Also:** Canadian Spec cars can do the short programming procedure but must have the dealer perform the long programming procedure.
> - **Also:** European Spec cars cannot do the short or long procedure. All FOB programming must be done by the dealer.
> - **Also:** This can be a long time “on battery”, it may be a good idea to hook a battery tender up to the car during programming to insure that you don’t discharge the battery to where the programming fails or the car won’t start.
> - **Also:** It has been reported that having a cell phone on your person, during the long method, may cause interference and not allow you to get the correct response for Step #9.